# Calling Amazon Payfort Tokenization API in angular as HTTPClient is throwing CORS error

Tags: angular, httpclient, payfort

Calling Amazon Payfort Tokenization API in angular as HTTPClient is throwing CORS error, how can i resolve this, or is there way to call Payfort Tokenization API  as ajax not as HTTP POST FORM.
Thanks in advance

i tried using HTTP POST FORM and it worked, but i want using HTTPClient (ajax) to get the response not to be redirected to POST URL.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.